# Bootstrap grid not stacking as expected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I may have miss understood how the grid wrapping in bootstrap is suppose to work but In the code below (the bulk of each table is dynamic which I have removed for the simplicity sake).  If there is no dynamic data everything stacks as I would expect but with data (which will most likely never be the same) it stack strangely.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or telling me what I have done incorrectly?

This is what I am seeing

[image]

This is what I thought I'd see
[image]

I have the following code :

```
        <div class="row">


            <div id="centerCol" class="col-md-3 clearfix">



<div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>Daily Site Totals</h3>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
        <tr>
            <th>Day</th>
            <th>Logins</th>
            <th>Distinct Logins</th>
            <th>Avg Min On</th>
            <th>New Accts</th>
            <th>Index Taken</th>
            <th>Reports Viewed</th>
            <th>Purchases Made</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>Site Totals</h3>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
        <tr>
            <th>Logins</th>
            <th>Distinct Logins</th>
            <th>Avg Min On</th>
            <th>New Accts</th>
            <th>Index Taken</th>
            <th>Reports Viewed</th>
            <th>Purchases Made</th>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>Affiliate Totals</h3>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
        <tr>
            <th>Affiliate</th>
            <th>Logins</th>
            <th>Distinct Logins</th>
            <th>Avg Min On</th>
            <th>New Accts</th>
            <th>Index Taken</th>
            <th>Reports Viewed</th>
            <th>Purchases Made</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>Top Logins</h3>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Logins</th>
            <th>Distinct Logins</th>
            <th>Avg Min On</th>
            <th>New Accts</th>
            <th>Index Taken</th>
            <th>Reports Viewed</th>
            <th>Purchases Made</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>


<div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>Top Referring People</h3>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Logins</th>
            <th>Distinct Logins</th>
            <th>Avg Min On</th>
            <th>New Accts</th>
            <th>Index Taken</th>
            <th>Reports Viewed</th>
            <th>Purchases Made</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>


                <br clear="all">
            </div>


        </div>
```

Comment: This is the way floats work. I tend to use shuffle or masonry. http://designshack.net/articles/css/everything-you-never-knew-about-css-floats/

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use 2 columns like this..

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/tHDqmM50ya

Comment: I was about to answer same as Skelly did.
This will definitely solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can arrange your code this way.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Daily site totals
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div>
        Site Totals
      </div>

      <div>
        Affiliate Totals
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- .row -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Top Logins
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Top Referring People
    </div>
  </div><!-- .row -->
</div><!-- .container -->
```

use two .row classes to clearfix the float.